# Adapt a new Apple Framework class to a previous iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ipad, sdk

I'm using a new API class, NSJSONSerialization, especially the following method :

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

I'd like to stick as much as I can to the tools Apple is giving us, but this class is only available on iOS 5.

Is there a way to re-implement the class and its method for iOS 4 so it can call an external JSON framework (JSONKit) by using the exact same call methods ?

```
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:0 error:nil];
```

If I create a class with the same name (NSJSONSerialization) it will not compile (duplicate interface).

I can't create a category either, because it will simply ignore any NSJSONSerialization related calls due to its unavailability on iOS 4.

Any help ?

Comment: Then why not use JSONKit anyway?

Comment: Because like I said, i'd like to stick as much as I can to the tools provided by Apple. But yeah, I guess it would be simpler to stick with JSONKit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you should create your on JSON class and inside it check if NSJSONSerialization is present and use it otherwise fallback to JSONKit.

Check this [AFNetworking implementation](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFJSONRequestOperation.m#L121) to get the idea

Comment: Ok. I thought of it, but I was wondering if there was another solution, like implementing the NSJSONSerialization by myself for earlier SDK.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to re-implement a standard API by yourself. It will make your code more confusing with no apparent benefits.